# Is this usage of the verb "conclude" appropriate?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

I have these three sentences:

> Throughout human history, mental illness has been stigmatized beyond
>   belief.  Individuals that have been diagnosed as mentally ill have
>   been subject to social opposition.  Stigma researchers from University
>   of Chicago, Patrick W. Corrigan and Amy C. Watson, conclude these
>   statements and believe that public and self-stigma both affect the
>   society diagnosed with mental disorders.

Is it ok to use the term "conclude these statements" as in the third sentence above?  I am asking this because that phrase doesn't seem accurate to me.

Comment: ... have drawn these conclusions...

Comment: The last part "society diagnosed with mental disorders" seems weird.  The whole society has mental disorders?!?

Comment: what about: "conclude these findings" ?

Comment: Why do you think it would or wouldn't be okay? Explain why you're here asking a question.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I just updated the question.  This is my very first question here and I don't understand why it is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *conclude something*, it means, *to finish doing something*, so your sentence reads:

"[The researchers] finish making these statements and believe ..."

What you want to say is *conclude (that)*, which means to decide something is true based upon evidence. Here's a possible rewording:

"[The researchers] conclude (that) these statements are correct and believe ..."

The *that* is optional in this case and doesn’t change the meaning.